# How do i show wordpress attachments from current post?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, attachment

So with my blog i have a photo attachment page but it only shows to photo's at a time, and those two photo's are used as the navigation and i hate that.

I want the attachment page to show all the photo's that goes along with the rest of that set.

Here is the current code

```
        <div id="nav-images" class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link() ?></div>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link() ?></div>
```

How do i change that to show all the post attachments?

Answer (score 5):

To clarify, this doesn't work anymore - at least with version 3.5.2. I used this instead;

```
$attachments = get_children(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
  )
);
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
  // ...
}
```

Only resurrecting an old thread because this one ranks quite highly for this search term.

Answer (score 3):

When you're on a page or post, you can get all of its attachments with the following:

```
global $post; // refers to the post or parent being displayed
$attachements = query_posts(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',  // only get "attachment" type posts
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,   // only get attachments for current post/page
    'posts_per_page' => -1        // get all attachments
  )
);
foreach($attachements as $attachment){
  // Do something exceedingly fancy
}
```

Since you're currently on an attachment page, you can get all the other attachments using the `$post->post_parent` value:

```
global $post; // refers to the attachement object
$attachements = query_posts(
  array (
    'post_type' => 'attachment',  // only get "attachment" type posts
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,  // attachments on the same page or post
    'posts_per_page' => -1        // get all attachments
  )
);
```

To then display the attachment images, you can use the [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) function.  The attachment's ID will be available in each iteration of your foreach loop as `$attachement->ID` (if you use the same naming convention as my first example).

Answer (score -1):

Since WordPress 3.6.0 you can also use [get_attached_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media).

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
if(! empty($media)){
    foreach($media as $media_id => $media_file){
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( $media_id, 'thumbnail' );
        $full = wp_get_attachment_url( $media_id );
        echo '<a href="'.$full.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$thumbnail[0].'" alt="'.$media_file->post_title.'" /></a>';
    }
}
```